# Using AVAudioPlayer fail to play .m4a by Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I use Alamofire to download the iTunes search Api's trial music.
And when I download finished, I want to play the music.
I try to fix it, but it also no sounds to play.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Alamofire
import CryptoSwift

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let urlString = "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview18/v4/9c/db/54/9cdb54b3-5c52-3063-b1ad-abe42955edb5/mzaf_520282131402737225.plus.aac.p.m4a"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let fileName = self.urlString.md5()
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).m4a")
            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination).response { response in

            if response.error == nil {

                var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

                do {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: response.destinationURL!)
                    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    audioPlayer.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Error:", error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? What happens, what error messages are you seeing?

Comment: No sounds to play

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that `audioPlayer` is a local variable, therefore it gets deallocated when you leave the scope of completion closure. Because `audioPlayer` isn't retained anywhere else, the moment you leave the closure's scope, `audioPlayer` reference count is equal to `0`, which causes ARC to deallocate it.

Also, you use force unwrapping operator - `!` - a lot, which is:
1) incorrect
2) unsafe
Use either `if let` construct or `guard` statement

What you need to to is store the player as instance variable of your `FirstViewController` class.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let urlString = "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview18/v4/9c/db/54/9cdb54b3-5c52-3063-b1ad-abe42955edb5/mzaf_520282131402737225.plus.aac.p.m4a"

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // (...)

        Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination).response { [weak self] (response) in

            if response.error == nil {

                guard let url = response.destinationURL else { return }

                do {
                    self?.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:  url)
                    self?.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                    self?.audioPlayer?.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Error:", error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just move audioPlayer to controller

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let urlString = "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview18/v4/9c/db/54/9cdb54b3-5c52-3063-b1ad-abe42955edb5/mzaf_520282131402737225.plus.aac.p.m4a"
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

   //Downloading code......
}
```